# Best way of handling if a>b in a case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a better way of writing the following chunk of a query?

```
CASE WHEN ugt.Type = 'Permanent' 
            AND ISNULL(ug.lastpromotion,u.CreatedOn) < DATEADD(MM,-6,GETDATE())
        THEN 
            (
                SELECT  cast(sum(pc.CommissionPerc / 100) as numeric(3,1))
                FROM Placements p
                INNER JOIN PlacementConsultants pc on pc.PlacementId = p.PlacementID AND pc.UserId = @userid
                INNER JOIN PlacementInvoices PlI on PlI.PlacementID = P.Placementid
                WHERE p.CreatedUserId = @userid
                AND pli.CreatedOn 
                        BETWEEN DATEADD(MM,-6,GETDATE())
                        AND GETDATE()
            )
    WHEN ugt.Type = 'Permanent' 
            AND ISNULL(ug.lastpromotion,u.CreatedOn) > DATEADD(MM,-6,GETDATE())
        THEN 
            (
                SELECT cast(sum(pc.CommissionPerc / 100) as numeric(3,1))
                FROM Placements p
                INNER JOIN PlacementConsultants pc on pc.PlacementId = p.PlacementID AND pc.UserId = @userid
                INNER JOIN PlacementInvoices PlI on PlI.PlacementID = P.Placementid
                WHERE pc.UserId = @userid
                AND pli.CreatedOn 
                        BETWEEN ISNULL(ug.lastpromotion,u.CreatedOn)
                        AND GETDATE()
            )
END
```

As all that's changing is the pli.createdon needs to use the most recent out of the last promotion or 6 months ago. (i.e. count the number of deals since their latest promotion or 6 months ago, whatever is the most recent)?

Or am I stuck doing 2 cases for each type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a single `case`, just by enhancing the logic in the `where` clause:

```
CASE WHEN ugt.Type = 'Permanent' 
     THEN (SELECT  cast(sum(pc.CommissionPerc / 100) as numeric(3,1))
           FROM Placements p INNER JOIN
                PlacementConsultants pc
                on pc.PlacementId = p.PlacementID AND pc.UserId = @userid INNER JOIN
                PlacementInvoices PlI
                on PlI.PlacementID = P.Placementid
           WHERE p.CreatedUserId = @userid AND
                 pli.CreatedOn <= GETDATE() AND
                 ((pli.CreatedOn >= DATEADD(MM, -6, GETDATE()) AND
                   ISNULL(ug.lastpromotion, u.CreatedOn) < DATEADD(MM, -6, GETDATE())
                  ) OR
                  (pli.ISNULL(ug.lastpromotion, u.CreatedOn) AND
                   ISNULL(ug.lastpromotion, u.CreatedOn) >= DATEADD(MM, -6, GETDATE())
                  )
                 )
```

Wouldn't it be nice if SQL Server supported `least()` and `greatest()`?

Comment: +1 for mentioning least() and greatest() - you only realize how useful they are when you don't have them :-/

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked the question because I thought to myself "something this simple must exist surely?!" :D

Comment: While this answer is correct, I've just created a function to get the most recent date out of two dates and used that!

Answer (score 0):

You can move your case to the WHERE clause:

```
 AND pli.CreatedOn BETWEEN 
   IFF(ISNULL(ug.lastpromotion,u.CreatedOn) < DATEADD(MM,-6,GETDATE()),
         DATEADD(MM,-6,GETDATE()), 
         ISNULL(ug.lastpromotion,u.CreatedOn))
     AND GETDATE()
```